# How to apply salt and pepper noise to only specific part of the image using python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I have a image of size (1200 X 1000) and I am creating multiple patches (using sliding window of 256 X 256 with a stride of 10) out of it. My ultimate goal to supply the patches to the convolutional neural networks. I wish to introduce some salt and pepper noise to the patches generated out of the image. The image is nothing but screenshot of a webpage. Now I wish to make sure that the salt and pepper noise which I am adding doesn't fall on the HTML object regions of the patch which is generated. For e.g. Suppose I have radiobutton, textbox, selection dropwdown and buttons in the patch, I need to make sure that the noise generated shouldn't fall on these objects in the patch. Other than that, it could fall inside any other region in the patch.

I have written code for salt and pepper noise as follows:

```
  import numpy as np
  import os
  import cv2
  def noisy(image):
       row,col,ch = image.shape
       s_vs_p = 0.5
       amount = 0.004
       out = image
       # Salt mode
       num_salt = np.ceil(amount * image.size * s_vs_p)
       coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_salt))
          for i in image.shape]
       out[coords] = 1

      # Pepper mode
      num_pepper = np.ceil(amount* image.size * (1. - s_vs_p))
      coords = [np.random.randint(0, i - 1, int(num_pepper))
          for i in image.shape]
      out[coords] = 0
  return out
```

I have the coordinates of the html objects in the json file and have read and stored it into list of objects in my program. It contains X-Coord, Y-Coord, Width, Height and Type of the HTML object.

I have created a label matrix which is replica of the original image which has 5 classes:

0 : it is the default class value (i.e. is the region of the image excluding the HTML objects)
1: it is the value stored in the matrix for Textbox in the image

2: it is the value stored in the matrix for Button in the image

3: it is the value stored in the matrix for RadioButton in the image

4: it is the value stored in the matrix for selection in the image

So each of these values will represent specific HTML objects of the screen shot image in my Label Matrix.

Now, using the Label Matrix, How do I ensure that salt and pepper noise doesn't fall in the regions of the HTML objects in the patch created, is my challenge here.

Comment: I've modified my answer, hopefully this is what you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of crude, but why don't you apply the noise uniformly on a copy of the original picture, then copy the patches of each object from the original image back on top of that noisy image?

**EDIT after you rephrased your question**

Basically, you need to test whether `coords` falls on a place where your mask (your "label matrix") is equal to 0.
Here is what you could do (or something in that vein, I can't say my code is very pretty):

```
out = np.zeros((26,26))
# salt coordinates
coords = [np.random.randint(0,26,50), np.random.randint(0,26,50)]

# mask - 0 are regions where salt can be applied, otherwise don't touch
mask = np.zeros(out.shape)
mask[:13,:13] = 1
mask[-13:,-13:] = 2

# where does the salt coordinates land on the mask
a = mask[coords]

# find points where mask is 0
b, = np.nonzero(a==0)

# copy from coords only where mask is 0
valid_coords = np.array(coords)[:,b]

# apply salt on valid coordinates
out[valid_coords.tolist()]=1
```

[image]